# workerize-loader failed to work after compiling (react typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, rust

I created a rust-wasm module and use workerize-loader to load it:

```
export const getQRCode = async (
  arg: string,
  width: number,
  height: number
) => {
  const { qrcode } = await import('uranus-qrcode');
  return qrcode(arg, width, height);
};
```

and then I use the worker as such:

```
// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import qrCodeWorker from 'workerize-loader!workers/qrCodeWorker';

...
  const workerizeQRLoader = async () => {
    try {
      const instance = qrCodeWorker();
      const qr = await instance.getQRCode(href, 150, 150);
      setQRCode({
        __html: qr
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  };
...
  useEffect(() => {
    workerizeQRLoader();
    // qrLoader();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
...
```

The above works in dev mode, but after compiling it says:

```
TypeError: a.getQRCode is not a function
    at 8.a2ac9b2e.chunk.js:1
    at l (0.69608c56.chunk.js:2)
    at Generator._invoke (0.69608c56.chunk.js:2)
    at Generator.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (0.69608c56.chunk.js:2)
    at r (0.69608c56.chunk.js:2)
    at s (0.69608c56.chunk.js:2)
    at 0.69608c56.chunk.js:2
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at 0.69608c56.chunk.js:2
    at 8.a2ac9b2e.chunk.js:1
```

If I import the rust-wasm module directly into the main thread it works:

```
...
  const qrLoader = async () => {
    const { qrcode: render } = await import('uranus-qrcode');
    const qr = await render(href, 150, 150);
    setQRCode({
      __html: qr
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // workerizeQRLoader();
    qrLoader();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
...
```

Basically I try to get React (Webpack & TypeScript flavor) to load WebAssembly modules (aka wasm, created via Rust-Wasmbindgen) through web workers.  I've tried workerize-loader + wasm-loader, and it works pretty well in the dev mode but once it is compiled, the prototype will not be added to the worker (suspecting it's a bug in workerize-loader because all workerized modules behave the same). I also tried to work with worker-loader + comlink, but the worker-loader doesn't seem to work with wasm-loader (would not be able to import wasm into the worker). The only way to get this to work is to load wasm into the main thread via wasm-loader and just give up the multi-threads setup which is basically a shame...so does anyone have successfully use a WebAssembly module loaded through a web worker in a React TypeScript project? What's your setup?

I also created a starter project: https://github.com/aeroxy/react-typescript-webassembly-starter.git

You can checkout the "workerize" branch and see how it works in dev mode but after compiling, it throws "not a function" error.

Comment: When you open the build app are there any errors in the network tab of the devtools? You could see if it's a problem with wasm or with workerize by creating a dummy worker that doesn't use wasm.

Comment: You could also try removing React.StrictMode and see if it breaks in dev, your effect has workerizeQRLoader but it could be a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: HMR no, i initially suspected as such, i don't think it even tried to load the wasm module. also when i load the wasm module directly it works just fine.

Comment: In fact in dev mode if I print out instance it is: `Worker {onmessage: null, onerror: null, getQRCode: ƒ}` but after compiling it becomes: `Worker {onmessage: null, onerror: null}`

Comment: I think it may have something to do with typescript / babel / react-scripts, and how they handle import / export...

Comment: @HMR I also created a starter project: https://github.com/aeroxy/react-typescript-webassembly-starter.git

You can checkout the "workerize" branch and see how it works in dev mode but after compiling, it throws "not a function" error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the workerize method works!

I've originally tried workerize-loader + wasm-loader, and it works pretty well in the dev mode but once it is compiled, the prototype will not be added to the worker (suspecting it's a bug in workerize-loader because all workerized modules behave the same). This indeed turns out to be a bug in workerize-loader (see [workerize-loader failed to work after compiling](https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader/issues/89) and [Version 1.2.0 does not export function on worker instance in production mode](https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader/issues/85)). After upgrading to the [workerize-loader 1.2.1](https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader/commit/d586b51aa0f3eda94aa5b3e7d9881c9d9b804cdc), it works in both dev and prod code.

I have updated the Master repo: https://github.com/aeroxy/react-typescript-webassembly-starter.git

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit much for a comment but I got some bad and good news. Executed the following commands using `node v12.16.1` and `yarn 1.22.4`:

```
git clone https://github.com/aeroxy/react-typescript-webassembly-starter.git
cd react-typescript-webassembly-starter
yarn # some warnings that packages need to be updated to later version
yarn start # dev version works
yarn build
cd build
npx serve
```

When opening the build version in `Google Chrome 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on my Fedora 31 I can see the qr code, no errors in console.

That means that there is no fault in the project (good news) but something maybe wrong in settings on your machine (bad news), the os you are using or some other machine specific difference.

You could try a to clone the project again and run the commands exactly like I did to see if that's working. Older npm could have some problems with cached packages but that's been fixed for a while now. A while ago you needed to change the repository for npm or use vpn because it was blocked, this could also be causing you trouble.